# Error highlighting in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, highlighting

When using Eclipse or NetBeans IDE on a Java project I get to see where errors in my code are, before and after compiling. The line causing the issue is shown. I remember that back in the old days, the Visual C++ 98' edition did do underlining of errors in the code. Is there a way to enable this in Visual C++ 2005? Or is there a 3rd party plugin to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need in order to do this is a static code analysis tool for C++ with a real-time plug-in for VS2005.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any open-source static code analyzers that plug into VS2005, but there are some commercial ones.  One such product that has been well-received is [Riverblade's Visual Lint](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/visual_lint/index.html).

In general, Googling "visual c++ static code analysis" is a good place to start hunting this type of software down.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Assist is also a useful tool. Works with all versions of visual studio.